# Types of users, inheritance issue with jpa and Play! Framework

Tags: inheritance, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to implement an inherited structure for user types in my application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User_") // Need this since "User" is a reserved name in SQL Server
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends Model {

    @Column(nullable=false,unique=true)
    public String username;

    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends User {
    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Client extends User {
    ...
}
```

---

When I do this, the `Employee` and `Client` tables that get created do not have any foreign keys to the `User_` table, nor does the `User_` table have any foreign keys to the `Employee` or `Client` tables. How can I make this happen?

Ideally, I'd like an `Employee.username` column that is a foreign key for `User_`, so I other tables can have references to `Employee.username`.

I'm using Play! Framework 1.2.5 and SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Are you sure that no foreign keys are created? `id` column should be a foreign key. Also, you can use `@Table(name="\"User\"")`.

Comment: (had to delete to edit comment) Use name without underscore `@Table(name="Users")` `Users` isn't restricted. Checked with Azure SQL.

Comment: axtavt, you're right. Upon closer inspection, the id is both the FK and the PK. I wasn't expecting that. Any way to actually have the username as a string show up in `Employee`? I want to be able to do this on other tables: `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="employee", referencedColumnName="username") public Employee employee;`

Comment: Also, thanks both of you for the table name suggestions, both work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since it's been a few days.

The first question I asked was:

> When I do this, the Employee and Client tables that get created do not have any foreign keys to the User_ table, nor does the User_ table have any foreign keys to the Employee or Client tables. How can I make this happen?

This was answered in the comments, thanks axtavt! It turns out that `id` is the Primary Key *and* the Foreign Key.

---

Next up, I wrote this in my question:

> Ideally, I'd like an Employee.username column that is a foreign key for User_, so I other tables can have references to Employee.username.

And clarified / worded as a question in comments:

> Any way to actually have the username as a string show up in `Employee`? I want to be able to do this on other tables:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employee", referencedColumnName="username")
public Employee employee;
```

I was never able to find an adequate answer to this, so I'm making do with the default (using the numeric id field):

```
@ManyToOne
public Employee employee;
```

I'll be happy to accept another answer if this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html

Also, please note that you should implement a discriminator value.

You can reaad up on the topic here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168

Comment: I tried implementing both `@DiscriminatorValue` and `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` before, but they didn't appear do to anything, so I got rid of them. Maybe I did it wrong...

Comment: Googling will find you some examples of use for both of it.